# What is Helios in Asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, helios

I have some query regarding helios framework.
Q1 What is Helios in Asp.net?
Q2 Can we use asp extension like(razor pages and aspx pages) using them.

Some articles says...

> One of the core reasons is the performance-factor. Helios will be able
>   to achieve 2x-3x more throughput than standard ASP.Net application. In
>   terms of memory consumption, Helios is much better than System.Web
>   dll. In a taken benchmark Helios architecture allowed a sample
>   application to achieve 50000 concurrent requests with approximately
>   1GB less overhead compare to a standard ASP.Net application.

So it is possible to use in asp.net application.

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2014/02/18/introducing-asp-net-project-helios/

Comment: Thanks for reply but i want more about it..

Comment: Like is it support mvc extension as well as .aspx extension for create web application.

Answer (score 0):

For those who stumbled upon this question like me, `Helios` was an IIS component used during development of ASP.NET Core (known then as ASP.NET 5 or ASP.NET vNext).

`Helios` was replaced by `HttpPlatformHandler` [Change to IIS hosting model #69](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/69)
which was subsequently replaced by `ASP.NET Core Module` [HttpPlatformHandler has been replaced by ASP.NET Core Module #164](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/164).

At the time of writing, this is the currently used solution for ASP.NET Core - see [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/aspnet-core-module?view=aspnetcore-5.0).